# Can you swap out the virtual DOM subsystem in ReactJS - if so, how?

Tags: reactjs

I overheard someone say this was possible: can you swap out the virtual DOM subsystem in ReactJS?

Presumably you'd do this if you wanted to render to a different platform?

What are the high level steps involved in writing your own virtual DOM subsystem and swapping it in?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is what the `react-dom` and `react-native` packages achieve, right?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I am looking for an overview of how to swap in anther renderer. I have updated my question with this.